# Is there any way to create a user in crowd using CLI or using some command?

Tags: powershell, curl, atlassian-crowd

Is there any way to create a user in crowd using CLI or using some command?

I get 403 prohibited error when ever I try accessing the crowd using curl command i.e `curl -X GET http://<crowd link>:8095/crowd/rest/usermanagement/1/user?usernamedeepak`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be nice if you posted some code you already have and list the issues you have with that so that community can help you. [so] is not free code writing service so showing your effort will increase chances for getting good answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the [REST api](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/3.2.3/REST/) to create users, as you've been trying to.

Note that the `/usermanagement` resources require you to authenticate (using basic auth) with an application's credentials (as they're meant to be used by connected applications), and will affect the directories associated with that application in the Crowd configuration screen.

You'll also need to make sure the 'Remote addresses' section of the application configuration, lists your IP address as allowed to connect (or you can add `0.0.0.0/0` there, to allow all connections for that application.

So to recap, what you probably want to do is:

1. Create a new application in Crowd connected to the directory you want to manipulate
2. Set the credentials for the application
3. Set the remote addresses for the application, to allow connections from the host you're trying to connect from
4. Use the [usermanagement/1/user](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/3.2.3/REST/#usermanagement/1/user-addUser) REST resource with curl or other http client, using basic auth to authenticate as the configured application

Disclosure: I'm one of the developers working on Crowd.

Comment: Thank you miszobi.I tried with curl and Invoke-Rest method (in powershell) .I failed with the basic auth process.I am getting 403 forbidden response.It would be help full if you can share the exact command using curl.Thank you once gain in advance.
curl -i -u usernamr:password http://*********:8095/crowd/rest/usermanagement/1/search?entity-type=user --header 'Accept: application/json'
Currently I am using the following command.

Answer (score -1):

Crowd has a lot of features in the cmdline itself.

`crowd [--help] (-a|--action) <action> [(-f|--file) <file>] [--encoding <encoding>] [--debug] [-v|--verbose] [--quiet]
  [--outputFormat <outputFormat>] [--sql <sql>] [--driver <driver>] [--url <url>] [--host <host>] [--port <port>] [--database
  <database>] [--continue] [--simulate] (-s|--server) <server> (-u|--user) <user> (-p|--password) <password> [--login <login>]
  [--service <service>] [-l|--loginFromStandardInput] [--api <api>] [--directory <directory>] [--group <group>] [--userId <userId>]
  [--userFullName <userFullName>] [--userEmail <userEmail>] [--userPassword <userPassword>]`

**For user creation, you can use**

```
addUser - Add a new user.
         Required parameters: userId
         Optional parameters: userFullName, userEmail, userPassword
addUserWithFile - Add users from comma separated file.
         Required parameters: file
```

Refer the [USAGE](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CRDCLI/overview) link for reference.

You can further use REST APIs to create the user. Refer the [REST API LINK](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/howto-create-crowd-user-using-REST/qaq-p/489319)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that this is a third-party add-on, and isn't available in Crowd itself.

Comment: @miszobi: Yes , I second you

Comment: Thank you Ranadip dutta.Your answer was really helpful.

Comment: @deepaktr: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciable.